# C++ REST SDK (Casablanca) - How to get HTTP Proxy settings

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I am using the Casablanca C++ REST SDK to perform a web request, however I would like the code to be smart enough to detect any system proxy settings.  In C#, I believe this is as easy as:

```
WebRequest.DefaultProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

But how can I do the equivalent in C++ using the REST SDK library?
I have the following code so far but it requires manual setting of the proxy information:

```
http_client_config config;

// Set proxy information if it's enabled
if (_bClientProxyEnabled)
{
    config.set_proxy(web::web_proxy(web::uri(utility::conversions::to_string_t(_sClientProxyServer))));
    credentials cred(utility::conversions::to_string_t(_sClientProxyUsername),
        utility::conversions::to_string_t(_sClientProxyPassword));
    // Set credentials
    config.set_credentials(cred);
}

http_client client(utility::conversions::to_string_t(this->serverUrl.c_str()), config);

// Build request URI and start the request.
uri_builder builder(utility::conversions::to_string_t(serverEndpoint));
```

Any ideas on how to make this code automatically detect the default system proxy?

Comment: This material may help. There are suggested answers involving Windows Registry lookup for proxy settings with a powershell script. https://serverfault.com/questions/696020/retrieve-internet-proxy-server-address-via-powershell

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384095(v=vs.85).aspx  WinHttpGetDefaultProxyConfiguration function

Comment: Thanks, Richard - the WINAPI function does look like it's of interest!  I was thinking that the REST API might have had some helper functions ;)

Comment: From what I have read the whole proxy thing seems to be a kind of default standard on the honor system and any application is free to do something else on its own. I think this fetches the Windows IE and Internet proxy settings but an individual application may ignore these settings.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  I will have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

cpprestsdk loads and ueses the [configured proxy setting](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/bfe34877914fd280512c97d41aaa99e88564fd8d/Release/src/http/client/http_client_winhttp.cpp#L834) and the associated (if any) credentials in it's windows http_client by simply specifying:  `config.set_proxy(web::web_proxy(web::web_proxy::use_auto_discovery));` which otherwise [defaults](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/bfe34877914fd280512c97d41aaa99e88564fd8d/Release/include/cpprest/details/web_utilities.h#L156) to: `web::web_proxy::use_default`